# Log4Net logging error just once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am trying to log error using log4net in asp.net MVC5 c#.

For test purpose, I have configured log4net in application_start and initialize logger and log error from home controller. For some reason, log4net only logs error for the first time when I start the application. When I navigate away from homecontroller and come back to home controller again, no error is logged. I have put my logging code in HomeController index. When debugged using breakpoint, the logging code is reachable but the log is not recorded.

Am I missing anything?

Here is my log4net configuration.

1. Configured log4net in Global.asax Application_Start() as

   ```
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
   ```
2. In my home controller index (For Testing), I am logging error as

   ```
   var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int rndint = rnd.Next(52);

   logger.Error(rndint.ToString());
   ```
3. My config file is using standard log4net `AdoNetAppender` with buffer size=100 and level is set to `WARN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdoNetAppender` batches log statements that are inserted into the database. If you set the buffer size to 1 you will see the log statements are added to the table immediately.

The best thing to do is use a buffer size of `1` for local development, and use a larger value when deployed to production if performance is a concern and lots of logging is used.

Comment: That was it.Thanks a lot. I was banging my head all this morning.